# How do I not specify a CustomerWeightField when scripting CustomerDerivedTA_ba?

Tags: arcpy, business-analyst

When you run the Business Analysis toolbox wizard for creating a Customer Derived Trade area, you have the option of weighting each customer by count or for specifying a field (such as sales or number of visits) to use as a weight. You select this with radio buttons and if you select "count", then you don't have to specify a field.

However, when scripting this tool, the CustomerWeightField is a required field. Leaving it blank yields a "This field was not found in the customer layer" type error message. In my case, I just want to use the count as the customers I'm analyzing do not have any other valid fields for weighting the results.

Is there a magic value to enter for CustomerWeightField that will force it to use count?

The documentation says:

> The field used to calculate the trade areas. This is based on either
>   the number of customers (count) or the calculated weighted value
>   assigned to each customer.

A fallback, I guess, would be to add a weight field and set it to 1, but I don't want to have to rely on modifying the input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but in my particular case, the store ID field was numeric, so since the tool filters by store ID, then uses the weights on that filtered set to build the trade areas, I just specified the CustomerWeightField to be the Store ID field. So, even if the Store IDs are like 51234, 100001, and 99, the weights don't matter relative to each other. All of the customers for the first store would be weighted 51234 and all the customers for the third store would be weighted 99, but since the weight is constant, it cancels out. At least it seems to.